# Why can I use RMagick from irb but not rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

ruby 1.9.2p320
rails 3.0.8
Fedora release 16 (Verne)

Did:

yum install imagemagick
yum install ImageMagick-devel
gem install RMagick with no problems at all

I can run RMagick from standalone Ruby programs, but Ruby on Rails (using
same interpreter) can't find RMagick:

```
gremlin:eric cars01 $ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'RMagick'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Magick::Version
=> "RMagick 2.13.1"
irb(main):003:0> $".grep(/Magick/)
=> ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick.rb"]
irb(main):004:0> 
gremlin:eric cars01 $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.8)
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> require 'RMagick'
LoadError: no such file to load -- RMagick
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'
```

If I put RMagick in the Gemfile, with or without its version, bundle says it
can't find the gem on the machine.  But it works with other gems.

Anyone have any ideas why Ruby can load RMagick outside Rails but not in it?

For the meantime the super-cool workaround of pushing the path to RMagick on $: before loading it works.

Comment: As xdite points out below, it's because `rails console` uses a different gem environment. Try running `bundle exec irb` for a more apt comparison.

Comment: Sure. The problem is that I can't get bundle to create an RMagick gem in vendor/cache. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

add this line in your Gemfile

`gem "rmagick"`

then `bundle install`

Comment: I tried that, but here's what happened:

gremlin:eric cars01 $ bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Could not find gem 'RMagick (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is your may have 2+ ruby, check below:

- which ruby
- which irb
- which bundle
- which gem

They are definitely in different places. You must make sure they are using the same enviorment.

Comment: No, they're all in the same directory.  I installed ruby from source, and none of those programs are elsewhere on the path


gremlin:ericp ~ $ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
gremlin:ericp ~ $ which irb
/usr/local/bin/irb
gremlin:ericp ~ $ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
gremlin:ericp ~ $ which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
gremlin:ericp ~ $